# How does Windows determine the order in which to copy files?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

This relates to copying files by dragging and dropping in Windows Explorer.

Imagine you have a directory containing a series of files with names like `Document01, Document02, Document03 ...` and so on.

Normally, if you select the files in the directory and copy by dragging and dropping, the files will copy in the order in which they were sorted (except that the file you dragged from will copy first). However, if you copy the entire directory, the order in which the files within it are copied seems to be random.

How does Windows decide the order in which it copies these files?

Comment: it's similar to copy commands in shells: the filename order is whatever returned by the file system: [In which order does command COPY copy files from source to destination?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44204762/995714)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't do anything specific, so they wind up being copied in the order the filesystem presented them to Explorer. That order will depend on the filesystem.